# Nominatim retrieving different data for the same request

Tags: node.js, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I'm using the Nominatim API to get the bounding boxes and polygon points of some local streets for a project.

An issue I found is that when I request an URL on my web browser, for example:

[Rua de Santa Maria](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Rua%20de%20Santa%20Maria,Madeira&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1)

It retrieves this bounding boxes:

```
["32.6474594","32.64779","-16.8998967","-16.8993021"]
["32.6469257","32.6470059","-16.8981943","-16.8974107"]
["32.6478793","32.6478838","-16.9007069","-16.9005973"]
["32.6478902","32.647988","-16.9014895","-16.9007494"]
```

But when I use the same URL for the request using a Node.js application:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = encodeURI("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?" + 
    "q=Rua de Santa Maria,Madeira&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1");

request({url: url, json: true}, function (err, res, json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

It retrieves:

```
["32.6470059","32.647067","-16.8984633","-16.8981943"]
["32.6469257","32.6470059","-16.8981943","-16.8974107"]
["32.6480316","32.6480782","-16.9021559","-16.901742"]
["32.6478793","32.6478838","-16.9007069","-16.9005973"]
```

Which is slightly different. The polygon points retrieved are also different. Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: The reason is very straightforward, there are many places named as "Rua de Santa Maria,Madeira" or there are redundant data in OSM.  In this case, you either have to choose one manually but could not rely on program itself and you can apply more conditions to filter out the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests are very likely not the same. Your browser sends additional information in its request headers such as the preferred language. These additional information seem to influence the search result.